# Object scope outside a function in R

Tags: r, scope, global-variables, getter-setter, rscript

Below I will try to explain the issue I am facing in a simplistic manner.

- I have two R scripts in two files - `file1.R` and `file2.R`. The `file1.R` contains function `function1()`.
- The `file2.R` contains multiple constructor definitions within it - `constructor1(p1, p2)`, `constructor2(p3, p4)`, etc. Instances of these constructors are used within `function1()` present in `file1.R`. So, I use `source("file2.R")` as a first line in `file1.R`.
- In `file2.R`, the `constructor2(p1 = rep(1,length(object1)), p2)`, uses object1 that is created by `function1()` in `file1.R`.

The overall structure of `file1.R` looks like below:

```
source("file2.R")

function1 <- function()
{

#Read data
data <- readData()

# Second parameter for this function is a instance of constructor1 that is present in file2.R
object1 <- somefunction1(data, listObject$constructor1)

# Second parameter for this function is a instance of a constructor2 that is present in file2.R
# Constructor 2 uses object1 as an input parameter (shown in file2.R)
object2 <- somefunction2(object1, listObject$constructor2)

}
```

The overall structure of file2.R looks like below:

```
# List object 
listObject <- list()

#Instance of constructor 1
listObject$constructor1 <- constructor1(p1 = someValue, p2 = someValue)

#Instance of constructor 2
# This is where problem lies. How do I access object1 here?
listObject$constructor2 <- constructor2(p3 =  rep(1,length(object1)), p4 = someValue)
```

How should I define the scope of `object1` outside `function1()`? I tried to use getter and setter in R to achieve this, but I get a `node stack overflow` error. I suppose this error originates because I `source("file2.R")` before `function1()` in `file1.R` and `source("file1.R")` in `file2.R`. Without this, I get a `object1 not found` error as soon as R reads `source("file2.R")`.

Comment: You have `source` in both files? Seems you are complicating. This is reproducible. I suggest you `source` in one file only (file function1.R).

Comment: The getter-setter functions are in file function1.R and the getter function is used in file function2.R. How how this work then?

Comment: Just build a package ...

Comment: @Roland not sure how would that help

Comment: You would gave everything naturally in one namespace then ...

Comment: @Roland do you mean, the constructor should also be in `file1.R`? What if I would like to have the two things in separate files?

Comment: I said build a package. You can still keep the functions in separate files. You just put the package infrastructure on top instead of sourcing the files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with the scope of `object1`, it has to do with the infinite loop

```
source("function1.R") > source("function2.R") > source("function1.R") > etc
```

This first example reproduces the error.

---

```
# file: function1.R

source("function2.R")

function1 <- function(){
    object1 <- 1:10
    function2(p1 = object1, p2 = 2)
}
```

---

```
# file: function2.R

source("function1.R")

function2 <- function(p1, p2){
    p1 + p2
}
```

---

In a clean R session run:

```
source("function1.R")
```

> Error: node stack overflow

Now remove the line `source("function1.R")` from the second file, function2.R.

```
# new file: function2.R

function2 <- function(p1, p2){
    p1 + p2
}
```

---

Again in a clean R session, run:

```
source("function1.R")
function1()
#[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

The object created in the scope of `function1` can be passed to `function2` with no problems.

Comment: Thanks for this example. It looks pretty straight forward here, but when I try to do this in my R project I get `object not found` error. I will edit the question function to add more details.

Comment: @novicegeek Post a *minimal* example that reproduces the error. Many times the questions have too many code not needed to reproduce the problem, and this can be both distracting and scare answerers away.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry, I used the term function() in my initial description, whereas it was a constructor. I hope its more clear now. If not, I will try to generate a minimal example.